# OpenGAppsのインストールに失敗しました

Tags: android, linux, raspberry-pi

ラズベリーパイのLineageOS 18.1でOpenGApps(ARM 11.0 pico)をインストールしようとしたのですがERROR:64と出てインストールがキャンセルされます。どうしたらよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ERROR 64: Wrong architecture to set-up Open GApps' pre-bundled busybox
```

は[ダウンロードしようとしているバージョンがあっていない際に発生するようです。](https://github.com/TeamWin/Team-Win-Recovery-Project/issues/1070)
私は実機を持っていないので詳しいことはわかりませんが、[こちらのwiki](https://wiki.lineageos.org/gapps)や[これらのサイト](https://www.google.com/search?q=lineageos%2018.1%20gapps)を参考にして他のバージョンのダウンロードを試されてはいかがでしょうか

---

追記　 [このバーション](https://androidfilehost.com/?w=files&flid=322935)はいかがでしょう？

Comment: すみませんエラーにはアンマウントエラーと出るのですがどうしたらいいでしょうか？

Comment: wiki曰く
`The Google apps packages are not supported in any way by LineageOS.`
`Google apps should be installed via recovery immediately after installing LineageOS. Exact steps vary, and as such, you should see your device’s installation guide here for specific instructions.`
とのことですのでインストール直後にダウンロードするなりなんなりが必要だと思います。
詳細な情報は上記wikiにありますのでgoogle翻訳を用いてでもぜひご一読ください。

Comment: 重ね重ねありがとうございます！！

Comment: 参考にさせていただきます